# Marklogic latency : Document not found

Tags: cluster-computing, marklogic

I am working on a clustered marklogic environment where we have 10 Nodes. All nodes are shared E&D Nodes.
Problem that we are facing:
When a page is written in marklogic its takes some time (upto 3 secs) for all the nodes in the cluster to get updated & its during this time if I then do a read operation to fetch the previously written page, its not found.

Has anyone experienced this latency issue? and looked at eliminating it then please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's normal for a new document to only appear after the database transaction commits. But it is **not** normal for a commit to take 3-sec.

- Which version of MarkLogic Server?
- Which OS and version?
- Can you describe the hardware configuration?
- How large are these documents? All other things equal, update time should be proportional to document size.

Can you reproduce this with a standalone host? That should eliminate cluster-related network latency from the transaction, which might tell you something. Possibly your cluster network has problems, or possibly one or more of the hosts has problems.

If you can reproduce the problem with a standalone host, use system monitoring to see what that host is doing at the time. On linux I favor something like `iostat -Mxz 5` and `top`, but other tools can also help. The problem could be disk I/O - though it would have to be really slow to result in 3-sec commits. Or it might be that your servers are low on RAM, so they are paging during the commit phase.

If you can't reproduce it with a standalone host, then I think you'll have to run similar system monitoring on all the hosts in the cluster. That's harder, but for 10 hosts it is just barely manageable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to be clear, its not the commit which is taking time, its the read from the Marklogic which is taking time. Regarding - "It's normal for a new document to only appear after the database transaction commits", the transaction is committed (when inserting). But a READ operation is immediately after that in another transaction which is fired and it fails to read the same document which was inserted maybe 2 secs before. I guess due to latency and sync between the clustered nodes.

Comment: ML 5, Linux, Tier1 SAN, Document size doesnt really matter as we tested with documents sizes ranging from 2MB to 15 GB and they all have this problem. I am looking for ways to ensure that the immediate read operation can somehow avoid the latency caused because of the chit chat between nodes.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying: I misunderstood. What you're describing sounds like a performance optimization. Take a look at "distribute timestamps" under http://docs.marklogic.com/admin-help/http-server for details. You can try setting "distribute timestamps" to "strict". Or consider setting up your load balancer for client stickiness, so a client that performs an update will hit the same host for subsequent requests.

Comment: I guess the "distribute timestamp" option is not available in Marklogic 5 :-(. Can you point me how to set-up the client stickiness?

Comment: Configuration will be specific to your load balancer, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29#Persistence discusses the problem and some different techniques used. For example you might look for something like "source address affinity persistence". This could also be a good time to look into upgrading to ML7: it's a fairly easy path from ML5. Test your code first, but you might not need any changes at all.